# Mapping more than one variable and label to the bar-plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my dataframe

```
dput(LSC)
structure(list(WBC = c(23.8, 162.4, 77.1, 155.1, 135.4, 23.3, 
NA, 88.2), Age = c(72.2638888888889, 65.0833333333333, 65.6972222222222, 
59.7666666666667, 22.7361111111111, 71.1972222222222, 67.7805555555556, 
46.8888888888889), Pre_leukemic_burden = c(96.2, 98.14, 100, 
99.84, 81.5, 97.64, 93.32, 100), Donor = structure(1:8, .Label = c("L1", 
"L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8"), class = "factor"), 
    Survival = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Alive", 
    "Deceased"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

So here I have one variable which is survival I have more as well but and others are continuous variable.
My objective for each patient I want to show the level of each of the WBC,Leukemic burden and Age.

```
df.long <- gather(LSC, variable,value, -Donor,-Survival)
df.long

ggplot(data = df.long, aes(x = Donor, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()
```

The above piece of code does the job and i get like this
[image: plot]

Now I have more categorical variable one of them here is survival.So is there a way i can incorporate the **survival** label into the plot.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How about `facet_wrap(~survival, scale = "free_x")`

Comment: yes thank you .this my daily struggle biologist trying their hands on data analysis + data visualization its simple concept but didn't strike my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be feasible to combine the two variables into one?
Here is an example

```r
library(tidyverse)
data = structure(list(WBC = c(23.8, 162.4, 77.1, 155.1, 135.4, 23.3, 
                            NA, 88.2), Age = c(72.2638888888889, 65.0833333333333, 65.6972222222222, 
                                               59.7666666666667, 22.7361111111111, 71.1972222222222, 67.7805555555556, 
                                               46.8888888888889), Pre_leukemic_burden = c(96.2, 98.14, 100, 
                                                                                          99.84, 81.5, 97.64, 93.32, 100), Donor = structure(1:8, .Label = c("L1", 
                                                                                                                                                             "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8"), class = "factor"), 
                    Survival = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Alive", 
                                                                                       "Deceased"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                            -8L))

data.long <- gather(data, variable,value, -Donor,-Survival)
data.long = data.long %>%  mutate(surv_var = paste(Survival, variable, sep = "-"))

ggplot(data = data.long, aes(x = Donor, y = value, fill = surv_var)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_col).
```

[image]

Alternatively faceting by `Survival`

```r
           

ggplot(data = data.long, aes(x = Donor, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~Survival)
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_col).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are looking for a bar plot. I just wanted to offer this other way of representation. If your number of cases is larger, a bar plot will be much more difficult to read (this is true for the dot plot I'm showing, but to a lesser extent).

I named your data `df`.

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Age, Pre_leukemic_burden)) +
      ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(Age, Pre_leukemic_burden, label=Donor)) +
      geom_point(color="red") +
      facet_wrap(~Survival)
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(Age, WBC)) +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(Age, WBC, label=Donor)) +
  geom_point(color="gray50") +
  facet_wrap(~Survival)            
cowplot::plot_grid(p1,p2, nrow=2)
```

[image]

Comment: This is interesting way to put ,perhaps i can use to scale up for data where I have quite a bit of metadata